# split() issues in node.js + express

Tags: node.js, express

When I try to split a string in node I get the following error...

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'split'
```

Here is the split code I am using...

```
var query = req.query;

query.split(",");
```

I am using express to create my server, it seems like it is looking for a module, but isn't .split() a standard method with node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req.query` simply isn't a string; it's an object, created by parsing the query string in `req.url` into key-value pairs. Therefore it doesn't have a `split` method, since that's only for strings. If you need the literal text of the query string (like because it's not actually made up of key-value pairs), use `url.parse(req.url).query`.

Answer (score 0):

`req.query` is not a string, it's an object representing the query string:

```
// url: /something?id=1&key=value
req.query.id == 1
req.query.key == 'value'
```